# See navigation without hide it in small screens. MDL

Tags: material-design-lite

I use navigation layout.

https://getmdl.io/components/index.html#layout-section/layout

In 3 example we see that:
 *< !  -- Navigation. **We hide it in small screens**. -->*

Question: How make that navigation will NOT hide in small screens????

(Sorry for my bad English)

Answer (score 0):

< nav class="mdl-navigation mdl-layout--large-screen-only"> =>  < nav class="mdl-navigation">
Delete mdl-layout--large-screen-only.